# mod-rewriting a simple url to another

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can i rewrite this example:

url1: `http://www.mydomain.de/members/user1`

to url2: `http://www.mydomain.de/benutzer/user1`

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: if you can include the code rather than links it's be better

Comment: Hi Visuallife, actually i have no code and searching for a rewrite rule how i can archive this .

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.